# Access single route parameter from Laravel route containing multiple parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have a route defined as:

```
Route::domain('{subdomain}.' . config('app.domain'))->group(function () {
  Route::get('/some-url/{id}', function ($id) {
    return $id;
  });
});
```

When defining my routes, I utilize a domain parameter `{subdomain}` to capture the subdomain. However, upon accessing a URL like `https://subdomain.example.com/some-url/1`, I notice that the `$id` parameter in the closure contains the value of the subdomain (subdomain) instead of the intended ID (1). To address this issue, I must explicitly define both `$subdomain` and `$id` as parameters in the closure:

```
Route::domain('{subdomain}.' . config('app.domain'))->group(function () {
  Route::get('/some-url/{id}', function ($subdomain, $id) {
    return $id;
  });
});
```

By defining both parameters, I can accurately access the `$id` value. However, this approach becomes cumbersome when the subdomain parameter is unnecessary for all routes, complicating the closure signature unnecessarily.

Is there a more concise or efficient method to access route parameters without requiring them as dependencies in the closure functions?

Comment: `$request->route()->parameter(...)`

Comment: Can you fix the syntax errors in your code so it's clear what you're trying to do?

Comment: @miken32, I have fixed the syntax error.

Comment: So you're putting these routes in a group with a parameter, but you don't want to use the parameter? Why not just leave out the parameter then?

Comment: @miken32, subdomain parameter is required for grouping so that I can access these routes under dynamic subdomains to set `currentTenant` as it is multi-tenant application. I just don't need subdomain parameter in Controllers, hence I do not pass these as dependency to controllers. But I need to pass both `subdomain` and `id` in controller dependency even if I want only `id` in controller logic.

Comment: Couldn’t you just do that in middleware?

Comment: @miken32, I am doing all that in middleware. But I still need to define dynamic `subdomain` group parameter if I am using dynamic subdomains for my application. I am using `subdomain` parameter in middlewares. I do not need that parameter in controllers, yet I need to pass `subdomain` as dependency if I need to access other route parameters.

Comment: Ok but I’m saying you could just parse the host name without using a parameter. It’s accessible from the request object.